# Объединение блоков Try-Catch в один (Java)

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

Мне необходимо прочесть файл (путь к файлу вводится через командную строку), в котором представлена структура папки в виде "дерева". С помощью фильтра нужно найти количество внутренних папок и файлов, среднее количество файлов в папке и тд. Написал следующий рабочий, но громоздкий код.

```
public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       File file = new File(args[0]);
       if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
            long numberOfDirs = 0;
            try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
                 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
                    numberOfDirs = bufferedReader.lines()
                            .filter(line -> line.startsWith("|-"))
                            .count();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(numberOfDirs + " dirs");

            double numberOfFiles = 0;
            try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
                numberOfFiles = bufferedReader.lines()
                        .filter(line -> line.startsWith("|\t"))
                        .count();
                int result = (int) Math.round(numberOfFiles);
                System.out.println(result + " files");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
                double averageLength = bufferedReader.lines()
                        .filter(line -> line.endsWith(".mp3"))
                        .mapToInt(String::length)
                        .average()
                        .getAsDouble();
                System.out.println("Average file length = " + averageLength);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            double averageNumberOfFiles = numberOfFiles / numberOfDirs;
            System.out.format("%.1f", averageNumberOfFiles);
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли все вычисления вобрать в один блок Try-Catch, чтобы не запускать каждый раз `BufferedReader`? У самого не получилось, я начинающий. Буду признателен за помощь или подсказку.

Comment: Откройте один блок try, прочитайте bufferedReader.lines() в отдельную переменную и работайте с ней.

Comment: @ rhino_rus Можно подробнее? Или пример?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приблизительно так можно прочитать файл раз в список, и потом уже использовать многократно:

```
List<String> lines;
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
    lines =  bufferedReader.lines().collectTo(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

long numberOfDirs = lines.stream() 
        .filter(line -> line.startsWith("|-"))
        .count();
System.out.println(numberOfDirs + " dirs");

double numberOfFiles = lines.stream()
        .filter(line -> line.startsWith("|\t"))
        .count();
int result = (int) Math.round(numberOfFiles);
System.out.println(result + " files");

double averageLength = lines.stream()
        .filter(line -> line.endsWith(".mp3"))
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .average()
        .getAsDouble();
System.out.println("Average file length = " + averageLength);
double averageNumberOfFiles = numberOfFiles / numberOfDirs;
System.out.format("%.1f", averageNumberOfFiles);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё отлично работает. Единственный нюанс: у меня `.collectTo` не компилировался. Но просто `collect` прокатил :)